# how do I count the amount of prime numbers each thread has found Ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu, pthreads

I have created a system that uses a user defined amount of threads to count primer numbers from 1 to 10000 I want to find out how many each thread has found and output that at the end rather than printing each prime number. I figured out how to count the overall amount of prime numbers found (code below) but don't know how to count each individual thread. any help appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int gretval = 0;
struct threadArgs
{
    int start;
    int finish;
};

void *threadMain(void *p)
{
    struct threadArgs *pargs = p;
    int i, c;
    int nstart = pargs->start, nfinish = pargs->finish;
    pthread_t tid = pthread_self();

    for (i = nstart; i < nfinish; i++)
    {
        for (c = 2; c <= i - 1; c++)
        {
            if (i % c == 0)
                break;
        }
        if (c == i)
            gretval = gretval + 1;
        //printf("thread %ld : %d\n",tid,i);
    }
    pthread_exit(&gretval);
    return 0;
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *pretval1;
    int retval;
    int numThreads = 0;
    int i;
    printf("how many threads would you like to use?\n");
    scanf("%d", &numThreads);
    pthread_t thrID[100];
    struct threadArgs targs[100];

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        numThreads = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    if (numThreads > 0 && numThreads <= 100)
    {
        int chunkSize = 10000 / numThreads;
        for (i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
            targs[i].start = i * chunkSize;
            targs[i].finish = (i * chunkSize) + chunkSize;
            pthread_create(&thrID[i], NULL, threadMain, &targs[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
            pthread_join(thrID[i], &pretval1);
        }
    }
    retval = *(int *)pretval1;
    printf("*pretval1 = %d\n", retval);
}
```

Edited code from advice

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
struct threadArgs{
    int start;
    int finish;
    int counter;
};

void *threadMain(void *p){
    struct threadArgs *pargs = p;
    int i,c
    ;
    int nstart = pargs -> start, nfinish = pargs -> finish, nCounter = ++pargs -> counter;
    pthread_t tid = pthread_self();
    
    for(i=nstart; i<nfinish; i++){
        for (c=2; c<= i-1; c++){
            if(i%c == 0)
                break;
            }
            if ( c == i)
                nCounter++;
                printf("thread %ld : %d : %d\n",tid,i,nCounter);


    }
    pthread_exit(&nCounter);
    return 0;
}

void main(int argc, char **argv){
    void *pretval1;
    int retval;
    int numThreads = 0;
    int i;
    printf("how many threads would you like to use?\n");
    scanf("%d", &numThreads);
    pthread_t thrID[100];
    struct threadArgs targs[100];
    
    if ( argc > 1){
        numThreads = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    if (numThreads > 0 && numThreads <= 100){
        int chunkSize = 10000/numThreads;
        for (i=0; i<numThreads; i++){
            targs[i].start = i*chunkSize;
            targs[i].finish = (i*chunkSize)+chunkSize;
            targs[i].counter = 0;
            pthread_create(&thrID[i], NULL, threadMain, &targs[i]);
            }
            for (i=0; i<numThreads; i++){
                pthread_join(thrID[i], &pretval1);
            }
    }
    //nCounter = *(int *)pretval1;
    //printf("*pretval1 = %d\n", nCounter);

}
```

Comment: I bet a `count` member in that `threadArgs` structure, initially zero, would come in pretty handy for this task.

Comment: So instead of gretval change the thread args, then int nCounter -> counter then increment counter instead of gretval and pthread_exit the counter?

Comment: Everything except `pthread_exit` on the counter. that's pointless. The modified `counter` field will be available back in `main` for any `targs[i]` once the associated thread is joined. Be sure to also put `targs[i].counter = 0;` with your `start` and `finish` member initialization prior to the thread start, so you know each thread's counter starts at zero. Within the thread proc you modify the counter via `++pargs->counter;`, for example, if you want it bumped.

Comment: I modified the code and the outputs are all strange now... its outputting every number and the amount it has found i'm baffled honestly. ill edit post with new code.

Comment: Don't throw  code hoping it sticks. You're over thinking this. [Look here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00631f7e5432fd4c). That hard codes the number of threads to 4, but you can still dynamically read it if you want

Comment: out of interest is there a way to do this using pthread_exit? the code above makes a lot more sense it's just out of interest :) thank you so much for your help incrementing the counter confused me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @WhozCraig I found the answer to my question! posting so this can be closed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct threadArgs{
    int start;
    int finish;
    int counter;
};

void *threadMain(void *p)
{
    struct threadArgs *pargs = p;
    //int limit;
    for (int i = pargs->start; i < pargs->finish; i++)
    {
        int c;
        for (c = 2; c < i; ++c)
        {
            if (i % c == 0)
                break;
        }

        if (c == i)
            if(pargs -> counter <= 4){
            ++pargs->counter;
          } else {
            pthread_cancel(pthread_self());
          }

    }
    pthread_exit(p);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int numThreads = 0;
    printf("how many threads would you like?\n");
    scanf("%d",&numThreads);

    pthread_t thrID[100];
    struct threadArgs targs[100];

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        numThreads = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    if (numThreads > 0 && numThreads <= 100)
    {
        int chunkSize = 10000 / numThreads;
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i)
        {
            targs[i].start = i * chunkSize;
            targs[i].finish = (i + 1) * chunkSize;
            targs[i].counter = 0;
            pthread_create(&thrID[i], NULL, threadMain, targs+i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {

                    pthread_join(thrID[i], NULL);
                    printf("Thread %d : %d primes\n", i, targs[i].counter);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```